# How to determine a semi-sphere's point x-y-z coordinates?

Tags: computational-geometry, linear-algebra

I'm having serious problems solving a problem illustrated on the pic below.
Let's say we have 3 points in 3D space (blue dots), and the some center of the triangle based on them (red dot - point P). We also have a normal to this triangle, so that we know which semi-space we talking about.

I need to determine, what is the position on a point (red ??? point) that depends on two angles, both in range of 0-180 degrees. Doesnt matter how the alfa=0 and betha=0 angle is "anchored", it is only important to be able to scan the whole semi-sphere (of radius r).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1h1B.png

If anybody could help me, I'd be really thankful.

Kind regards,
Rav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the drawing it looks as if the position of the point on the sphere is given by a form of [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). Let `r` be the radius of the sphere; let `alpha` be given relative to the x-axis; and let `beta` be the angle relative to the x-y-plane. The Cartesian coordinates of the point on the sphere are:

```
x = r * cos(beta) * cos(alpha)
y = r * cos(beta) * sin(alpha)
z = r * sin(beta)
```

**Edit**

But for a general coordinate frame with axes `(L, M, N)` centered at `(X, Y, Z)` the coordinates are (as in dmuir's answer):

```
(x, y, z) = 
   (X, Y, Z) 
   + r * cos(beta) * cos(alpha) * L 
   + r * cos(beta) * sin(alpha) * M 
   + r * sin(beta) * N
```

The axes `L` and `N` must be orthogonal and `M = cross(N, L)`. `alpha` is given relative to `L`, and `beta` is given relative to the `L`-`M` plane. If you don't know how `L` is related to points of the triangle, then the question can't be answered.

Comment: It's almost what I'm looking for - except the blue triangle doesn't have to be parallel to XY, XZ nor YZ plane. We have only 3 points (blue dots) given. Nothing more ;-( i.e. http://i.imgur.com/iwrbU.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to find two unit length orthogonal vectors L, M say, in the plane of the triangle as well as the the unit normal N. The points on the sphere are

r*cos(beta)*cos(alpha) * L + r*cos(beta)*sin(alpha)*M + r*sin(beta)*N